# Error using class enumeration in class function (Type Method) in framework

Tags: swift, enums, frameworks

I have a pure-swift framework, with the following class that contains an enumeration and a Type Method (class function) as follows:

```
public class LearningAlgorithm
{
  public enum LearningCategory {
      case Regression
      case Classification
  }

...

  public class func getAlgorithmListForCategory(category: LearningCategory) ->[String]
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

and a program that uses it as follows:

```
    let tCategory = LearningAlgorithm.LearningCategory.Regression;

    let asAlgorithmList = LearningAlgorithm.getAlgorithmListForCategory(tCategory)
```

This gives me an error "LearningAlgorithm.LearningCategory' is not convertible to 'LearningAlgorithm'" on the last line above.

I have tried using literals in the call (LearningAlgorithm.LearningCategory.Regression), but that gives the same error

If I change the framework to put the enum outside of a class:

```
public enum LearningCategory {
  case Regression
  case Classification
}

public class LearningAlgorithm
{
 ...
}
```

and the calling code to:

```
    //!!  Default to the regression category
    let tCategory = LearningCategory.Regression;
```

-->This gives an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'LearningCategory' on the last line above

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: hmmm, I'm not getting an error on your second example

Comment: I seem to be having hit-or-miss luck on what swift sees in the framework.  Public variables in public classes (classes that are referenced without error by the program using the framework) are rarely seen.  Some public methods refuse to be recognized (even when others in the same class are).  It almost seems that Xcode has a cache of old framework manifests, and uses them instead of the updated framework file.  However, this is seperate from the problem I am asking help for...